# How do I get my local proxy server to return html to browser?

Tags: ruby, linux, sockets, ubuntu, proxy

I have managed to get a proxy server running.
It currently only sends hardcoded GET requests but that is fine for the time being.
The problem is that I don't know how I get the data I receive from the webserver to
show up in my browser. I can however print the body of the data in my terminal without any problem.
An unrelated problem is also that the returned data is a "302 Moved" error.
I'm very thankfull for any help!

```
require 'socket'

def handle_request(client, host, port, path)
  puts "0"
  socket = TCPSocket.open(host, port)
  request = "GET #{path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

  socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)
  socket.print(request)
  response = socket.read

  headers,body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2) 
  client.puts body
  puts body

  socket.close
end



server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop{
  client = server.accept
  host = "www.google.se"
  port = 80
  path = "/index.html"
  handle_request(client, host, port, path)

  client.close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run your program and point your browser at `http://localhost:2000`.